# get content of a selected item in a listbox with two databindings

Tags: windows-phone-7, listboxitem

i have a listbox that is populated this way with two Databindings ("Frage" and "Surenummer"):

in c#:

```
                           var filteredData = from c in xmlDatei.Descendants("quran")
                           //   where c.Attribute("VerseID").Value == isolatedStore["zaehler_koran"].ToString() // "2"
                           where (string)c.Element("nummer") == "3" // isolatedStore["zaehler_koran"].ToString()
                           select new xmlaufbau()
                           {
                               Frage = (string)c.Element("inhalt"),
                               surenummer = (string)c.Element("sura") + ":" + (string)c.Element("verse")
                           };


                           listBox2.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```

This works really fine, everything ok.

My problem is this:

When i select an item in the listbox, i would love to get the "surenmmer" of the selected
item in the listbox and display it in a textblock.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 (listBox2.SelectedItem as xmlaufbau).surenmmer
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you here.

but try this:

On the selection changed event fired by the listbox: TextBlock.text=listbox2.SelectedItem.surenummer